# Python converting a list into a dict with a value of 1 for each key

Tags: python

I have:

```
somelist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I want it so that, the list would convert to a dict

```
somedict = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 1, 'c' : 1, 'd' : 1}
```

So I did:

```
somedict = dict(zip(somelist, [1 for i in somelist]))
```

it does work but not sure if it's the most efficient or pythonic way to do it

Any other ways to do it, preferably the simplest way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use [`fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) for this:

```
somelist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
somedict = dict.fromkeys(somelist, 1)
```

You can also use a dictionary comprehension (thanks to Steven Rumbalski for reminding me)

```
somedict = {x: 1 for x in somelist}
```

`fromkeys` is slightly more efficient though, as shown here.

```
>>> timeit('{a: 1 for a in range(100)}')
6.992431184339719
>>> timeit('dict.fromkeys(range(100), 1)')
5.276147376280434
```

Comment: A dict comprehension would also work: `{key: 1 for key in somelist}`.   `dict.fromkeys` is clearly the best answer, but it's also good to know about dict comprehensions.